# Shutdown ScheduledExecutorService when killing service

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, threadpool

I have used `ScheduledExecutorService` for my jar file and i'm executing it as a service in linux machine. I'm stating service by `nohup` command and killing it with `kill` command. But i heard `ScheduledExecutorService` should be shut down when finishing use it. If not, it will keep the JVM running, even when all other threads have been shut down.

1. what happen to my `ScheduledExecutorService` thread when i kill the service?
2. if `ScheduledExecutorService` thread is not shutdown when killing service, how i shut it down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you kill the entire process externally then it will kill the `ScheduledExecutorService` at the same time since it runs inside the process.

This is not recommended though as it will kill your program in the middle of whatever processing it's doing. You might have partially written files for example.